# What does this formatspecifier mean?

Tags: c

Here is a bit of c code i have,i dont know what is the usage of this specifier !%2!s!%3!s!\ means ? this is the code shown below

```
dev.FormatMessage( _T(!%2!s!%3!s!\\"), level,

value, simplify() );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you end up with:

```
\\level!s!value!s!simplify!s!\
```

Comment: why we wanted this here ,,here is 's' means string?

Comment: @peter: I am not the author of your C code. Without context we cannot know what this format means, and what purpose this line of code has.

Comment: The `!s!` bit is still part of the format specifier; this is the Windows way of encoding format strings.

Answer (score 1):

It is a template that is passed to the [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function; the output from this function will substitute the strings pointed to by the *level* and *value* variables and the return value from the *simplify* function at the places between the percent sign and the second exclamation mark following it.

So, the output will be two backslash characters (the C compiler expects literal backslashes to be escaped, so it will only be two of them in the compiled program here), followed by the three substitutions, followed by a single backslash.